# Android- Zip file uploaded via Http post includes headers

Tags: android, upload, zip

I am using following code to upload a zip file from android app to a location. Observation is:
1. The zip file uploaded at server is not opening with windows explorer.
2. Winzip, 7-zip and other tools are able to open the zip uploaded at server.
3. The file when directly pulled from android device (via adb) can be opened by windows explorer. (means it is not corrupt).

I analysed the hex dump of uploaded zip and found that it contains the http headers at beginning. On removing the headers manually and re-saving it does the job. It looks like they are being sent in the body or the whole headers section is being misinterpreted as part of the body. I cannot avoid these headers as these are required by server scripts.

Thanks

Hex of file at server: -B8m4yaqs_DBT3duNEuQUqEqqIdnyHYXEtwW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileupload"; filename="crashLogs.ZIP"
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

HOW Can I upload Zip file without Headers getting saved in it?

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            HttpPost postRequest;
            MultipartEntity reqEntity;
            FileBody fileBody;

            postRequest = new HttpPost(serverUrl);
            postRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");
            postRequest
                    .addHeader(
                            "X-BRB-Custom",
                            "veT14BAttolUAgiosgaultfOrTH93TAD30sag48feYbUlk45COInneBcaDegEARhowOfAYs10HELpsmump23");

            File zipFile = new File(Zip);
            try
            {
                reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

                fileBody = new FileBody(zipFile, "application/zip");
                reqEntity.addPart("fileupload", fileBody);

                postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(postRequest);

                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {
                    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
                    return deleteFiles();
                }

            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            return false;
```

Comment: Can you post server side code also? And have you got the solution? Pls post it too. Thanks..